# Lambda layer in model

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, keras

I'm super confusing with lambda layer during functional API

Some examples show me how to use lambda layer
and when they stack operation layer, some use lambda and some don't use

For example

```
D = Input((n,))
E = Lambda(tf.signal.fft)(D)
d = Model(~~~~)
```

or

```
D = Input((n,))
E = concatenate(D)
d = Model(~~~~)
```

Comment: I think you forgot the question.

Comment: Ahhhhh .sorry. My question is which is the correct answer. and if one case is impossible, then I wonder why is impossible